# How to associate a MAC address with an IP address

Tags: c++, ip-address, mac-address, netsh

I have an application where a (brain-dead) remote device sends BOOTP packets to a W7 PC.
My PC program needs to be able to communicate with this device. The obvious way to do this is for the program to take the MAC address from the BOOTP packet and associate
it with a given IP address, at which point sockets work just fine.

This can easily be done from an administrator command prompt using netsh, but it will be
a pain (tedious and error-prone) for my users to have to make this manual intervention at regular intervals, especially as all the required information is available to the program.

Is there any way this, or something equivalent, can be done from a program without requiring 
the user to elevate it with administrator rights? The best I can think of is to wrap a netsh command with system(), but this still needs everything to run with admin rights.

Comment: Maybe this will help you? http://compnetworking.about.com/od/networkprotocolsip/f/convertipmacadd.htm